# rails order by created_at attribute of nested jsonb data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, jsonb

I have a bunch of customers that need to be sorted by the time they were "completed" according to our system. I can do it like this and it works ok:

```
customers = Customer.where(state: 'review').joins(:audits)
customers.sort_by { |c| c.onboarding_finished_at.to_i }
```

or...it did until it got onto our staging environment where we have enough customers with enough audits that it caused some major performance issues. Now i'm searching for a way to sort customers by the `created_at` attribute of the last state transition, but my query-foo is woefully inadequate.

this is a simplified version of the `audits` data associated with a customer. Note the `audited_changes` column which is `jsonb`:

```
irb(main):032:0> customers.last.audits.last
=> #<Audited::Audit id: 642691, auditable_id: 45517, action: "update", audited_changes: {"state"=>[0, 1]}, created_at: "2020-08-13 08:59:00">
```

I can access the audits but i can't for the life of me figure out how to get the last transition to state "1" (cause there could be multiple) and then pluck the `created_at` of that **and then** sort customers by that `created_at` value.

Any push in the right direction is very much appreciated!

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: @Kumar postgresql

Comment: @Kumar's solution is good, but as an alternative, consider migrating the audits table to eliminate the jsonb column. If this is possible, you will be able to improve performance through indexing. Can't tell from your sample whether you could migrate just the audits table, or would need to add a new audited_changes table, where audit has_many audited_changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can do an inner joins on the table and run a query to check second element of state array (assuming that's the structure for all the records) is 1.

```
Customer.includes(:audits).where("audited_changes->'$.state[1]' = 1").reorder("audits.created_at asc")
```

Let me know if that's what you're looking for